# How do you find a string/char inside another string that's in a vector in C++? [that works for me]

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I looked this up on multiple forum pages, not just stack overflow, and have tried many solutions from the 'Check if a string contains a string in C++' post, along with others, and tried almost every single solution posed but none of them seem to work for me? I tried the `vector[i].find(std::string2)` along with `if(strstr(s1.c_str(),s2.c_str())) {cout << " S1 Contains S2";}` along with

```
 std::string in = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,"
                     " sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua";
    std::string needle = "pisci";
    auto it = std::search(in.begin(), in.end(),
                   std::boyer_moore_searcher(
                       needle.begin(), needle.end()));
    if(it != in.end())
        std::cout << "The string " << needle << " found at offset "
                  << it - in.begin() << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "The string " << needle << " not found\n";
```

and more solutions, (adapted to my code), but none have worked. The only one I didn't try was `std::string.contain()` but that's because visual studios (2019 v.142 -if that helps) [C++ standard language I'm using, Preview - Features from the Latest C++ Working Draft (std:c++latest),] wouldn't recognize the function -because it wouldn't recognize the larger library for some reason. I even tried reversing the two variables in case I was mixing the two up, and was looking for the larger variable in the smaller one.

I'm rather new at C++ so I'm not great at problem-solving with stuff like this, so forgive my ignorance if you would.
Does the problem arise because what I'm looking for is in a vector? I created a `vector <string> names = {"Andrew John", "John Doe",};` with names in it, and am trying to 'peer' into it and find keywords, but again, nothing works. Is there a special function to call when looking for something in a vector? Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: How would you do this with a your eyes, a list of strings written on paper and a pencil so you could mark the found strings? A program will be very similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do you find a string/char inside another string that's in a vector in C++?

If the `std::vector<std::string>` isn't sorted, I would use [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Example:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    // A vector with some strings:
    std::vector<std::string> vec{
        {"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,"
         " sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua"},
        {"Foo bar"}};
                     
    std::string needle = "pisci";
    size_t pos;

    // find and save position in the found string
    auto it = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
                           [&needle,&pos](const std::string& str) {
                               return (pos = str.find(needle)) != std::string::npos;
                           });

    if(it != vec.end()) {
        std::cout << "Found needle at position " << pos
                  << " in string\n" << *it << '\n';
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YYrb7ch1c)

---

Let's take a closer look at the [*lambda expression*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) used in the `std::find_if`:

```
[&needle,&pos](const std::string& str) {
    return (pos = str.find(needle)) != std::string::npos;
}
```

A lambda is an instance of an anonymous class with an `operator()` which makes it *Callable*. You can it compare with a `struct` like below that has an instance named `foo` which can be called:

```
struct { void operator()() { std::cout << "foo1\n"; } } foo1;   // oldschool

auto foo2 = [](){ std::cout << "foo2\n"; };                     // lambda version:

int main() {
    foo1();  // calling foo1() - prints foo1
    foo2();  // calling foo2() - prints foo2
}}
```

In the lambda used in the `find_if` there is also `[&needle,&pos]`. This means that the constructed lamba will contain hold references to those two variables to be able to use them inside the function.

Compare with a plain `struct`

```
    std::string s1 = "S1";
    std::string s2 = "S2";

    struct { // struct capturing a string by reference
        void operator()() { std::cout << "foo1 " + s + '\n'; }
        std::string& s;
    } foo1{s1};

    // lamda capturing by reference
    auto foo2 = [&s2]() { std::cout << "foo2 " + s2 + '\n'; };

    foo1(); // prints "foo1 S1"
    foo2(); // prints "foo2 S2"
```

So, as you can see lambda functions and functional objects like the anonymous structs instances above have a lot in common.

The lambda in the answer captures two variables by reference, to "outside" variables, `needle` and `pos` and it takes an argument (`const std::string& str`) whenever it's called.

With that `str` it tries to find `needle` and assigns the result to `pos`

```
pos = str.find(needle)
```

`pos` is then compared with `std::string::npos`. If it's *not* `std::string::npos` the needle was found and the lambda will return `true` which stops the `std::find_if` function from looking further and returns an iterator to the found `std::string`. As a bonus, `pos` will still be set to latest value it was assigned - which is the position in the string where the needle was found.

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate, this worked! 
Part of the code went over my head a little, particularly the [&needle, &pos](const std::string& str) part, I hate to ask, but if you could explain how that works so I can implement it if needed in some future projects. If not it's fine, I just thank you for answering the question.

Comment: @Frank_Hamill You're welcome - and I added a small explanation. If you'd like me to explain it in more detail, please just make a comment here.

Comment: small explanation?? Nah mate that's a pretty damn detailed explanation, I couldn't ask for more, you even cited the lambda expression on cppreference, I understand it pretty well now, thanks.

Comment: @Frank_Hamill Great, glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code does not match your textual description.  You are not searching a vector of strings, but *a* string.  In fact, it seems to be based on the example in CPPreference.

> Found needle at position 43 in string
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua

And it works when I try it.

It might be overkill for your search, since you are only searching the string once.  You are probably better off with a simple `find`.

What this doesn't show at all is that you want it in a loop, with `in` replaced by each value in the vector of strings.  That's a simple `for` loop:

```
for (const auto& in : myvector) { ...
```